# Meteor: failed to decode downloaded font and OTS parsing error - invalid version tag

Tags: meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts, glyphicons

I've started using glyphicons in my meteor project with the twbs:boostrap package. Ever since I started using them I've been receiving the following warnings in my console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

What is causing this and how can I suppress these warnings or solve the problem?  The glyphicons work perfectly fine, it's just a pain to see the warnings all the time though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that the package you are using to import glyphicons has a bug in it and does not properly declare the font files' locations or does not have the font files properly added to the package itself.

Check the package maintainers issue tracker and in the meantime, download the glyphicons to your `public` directory and declare them in your own CSS file.

Comment: How do I declare them in my CSS file and where can I download the glyphicons?

Comment: Just copy-paste them from your bootstrap/fonts folder to you public/fonts folder

Answer (score 0):

After trying lots of other approaches, and lots of re-installs and checking meteor plus npm configurations, I have just fixed the issue by clearing out browsing data from Chrome (cached images and files) and then refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

Serkan Durusoy's answer above worked for me but here is a bit more detail on what I had to do.

1. Copy the font files from node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts to public/fonts
2. Add this to my main.css:

   @font-face {
     font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
     src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
     src: url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
   }

I copied the css from node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css and changed the path to match where I'd put the fonts.